# How to insert utf8 character data from android to codeigniter server

Tags: android, mysql, codeigniter, utf-8

I am trying to insert UTF-8 characters(Like username in hindi or tamil language) in MySql with Codeigniter framework.
Here is my android side code:

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uploadApi);

       try {
           List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs=new ArrayList<>();
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key1","विकिपीडिया"));
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key2","इण्टरनेट"));

           UrlEncodedFormEntity  form = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);

           httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
           response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

       } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
       } catch (IOException e) {
       }
```

and this is server side code in codeigniter:

```
    public function create()
{

             $name=$this->input->get_post("name") ;$text=$this->input->get_post("text");
             $type=$this->input->get_post("type");$contact=$this->input->get_post("contact");
             $mp=$this->input->get_post("mp");$mla=$this->input->get_post("mla");
             $position=$this->input->get_post("position");    
             $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
             $config['allowed_types'] = '*';
     $config['max_size']    = '20000';
     $config['max_width']  = '2000';
     $config['max_height']  = '2000';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image'))
    {
        $image="noimage.jpg";
                echo $this->upload->display_errors();

    }
    else
    {
        $data = $this->upload->data();
                    $image=$data['file_name'];

    }        

         $data['json']=$this->uploadmodel->insert($name,$image,$text,$contact,$mp,$mla,$type,$position);      
         echo "Thanks for Sharing";

}
```

All configuration is set to utf-8 in configuration file. 
**error** is i am getting all string like **?????????**
please tell me where i am doing wrong.
Thanks

Comment: would you explain some more about these methods? @Selvin

Comment: Does `data` contain a username in Hindi? Please add to the code declaration and initialisation of your string to a fake Hindi name.

Comment: of course it does @greenapps, while i tried some hindi names in place of the values.

Comment: make your table column collation to UTF-8!

Comment: If you do not fullfill my request i cannot test it for you. But if that´s what you want i wonder why you ask for help.

Comment: i updated my question @greenapps

Comment: Ok. But you should now first implement your UrlEncodedFormEntity call as Selvin suggested you to do.

Comment: I done it @greenapps Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added this line:

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
```

Although i tried with it also before.

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"utf-8"));
```

but the above runs successfully.